# Implement Retrofit to my note app and getting below error

Tags: android

**Logcat error**

```
2023-02-25 15:15:09.576 18889-18889/exampleapp.com.notes D/AddNoteActivity: Try Catch Block Failed.... Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int tweakup.ru.notes.models.DefaultResponse.getCode()' on a null object reference
```

*Please note*
Sending data from postman works perfectly as well checking database after every single post. I installed the app on my mobile phone and still getting same Logcat error. Retrofit Configuration is great but I can't not find anything to help me out with this error!

**Client API**

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static Retrofit RETROFIT = null;

    public static Retrofit getClient() {
        if(RETROFIT == null) {
            OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().build();
            Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().create();

            RETROFIT = new Retrofit.Builder()
                    .baseUrl("http://192.555.3.122/notes/note/")
                    .client(okHttpClient)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson)).build();
        }
        return RETROFIT;
    }
}
```

**API Interface**

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("create")
    Call<DefaultResponse> apiNoteAdd(
            @Field("title") String title,
            @Field("description") String description
    );
}
```

**AddNoteActivity**

```
public class AddNoteActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final String LOG_TAG = AddNoteActivity.class.getSimpleName();
    private ApiInterface apiInterface;


    EditText mEditTextTitle;
    EditText mEditTextDescription;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_note);

        findViews();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_save_note:
                if (checkInputs()) {
                    addNote();
                }
                return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
    
    private boolean checkInputs() {
        boolean status = true;
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditTextTitle.getText().toString().trim())) {
            mEditTextTitle.requestFocus();
            mEditTextTitle.setError("Note title is required!");
            status = false;
        }
        if (TextUtils.isEmpty(mEditTextDescription.getText().toString().trim())) {
            mEditTextDescription.requestFocus();
            mEditTextDescription.setError("Note description is required!");
            status = false;
        }
        return status;
    }

    private void addNote() {
        String title = mEditTextTitle.getText().toString().trim();
        String message = mEditTextDescription.getText().toString().trim();

        Retrofit retrofit = ApiClient.getClient();
        apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class);

        apiInterface.apiNoteAdd(title, message).enqueue(new Callback<DefaultResponse>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Response<DefaultResponse> response) {
                try {
                    if (response.body().getCode() == 200) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddNoteActivity.this, "Note created!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else if (response.body().getCode() == 400) {
                        Toast.makeText(AddNoteActivity.this, response.body().getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(AddNoteActivity.this, "Something went wrong", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Try Catch Block Failed.... " + e.getLocalizedMessage());
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<DefaultResponse> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.d(LOG_TAG, "API Failed.... " + t.getLocalizedMessage());
            }
        });
    }
    
    private void findViews() {
        mEditTextTitle = findViewById(R.id.edittext_title);
        mEditTextDescription = findViewById(R.id.edittext_description);
    }
}
```

**Internet permission in manifest**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

**DefaultResponse**

```
public class DefaultResponse {
    public int code;
    public String message;

    public DefaultResponse(int code, String message) {
        this.code = code;
        this.message = message;
    }

    public int getCode() {
        return code;
    }

    public void setCode(int code) {
        this.code = code;
    }

    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }

    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }
}
```

**Postman Response**

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "message": "Note successfully added",
    "result": 11
}
```

Answer (score 0):

finally I managed to solve my problem out. This is my Logcat error

```
2023-02-25 15:15:09.576 18889-18889/exampleapp.com.notes D/AddNoteActivity: Try Catch Block Failed.... Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int tweakup.ru.notes.models.DefaultResponse.getCode()' on a null object reference
```

The Retrofit response code 405 with message "method not allowed" was causing this problem. Because I annotate wrongly my method,

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("create") *---> HERE IS MY MISTAKE*
    Call<DefaultResponse> apiNoteAdd(
            @Field("title") String title,
            @Field("description") String description
    );
}
```

The annotation must match the API and changed to

```
public interface ApiInterface {
    @FormUrlEncoded
    @POST("add")
    Call<DefaultResponse> apiNoteAdd(
            @Field("title") String title,
            @Field("description") String description
    );
}
```